# PHP Bing Search API returns an empty array

Tags: php, bing

I am using the bing search API to lookup URLs like a company's twitters. After some use, it started returning this no matter how I changed the query or the formatting:

```
array(1) {
   ["d"]=>
     array(1) {
       ["results"]=>
         array(0) {
       }
     }
   }
```

I haven't changed my code that gets the request. Here's the query I'm using:

`Capital University%20twitter`

And this is the code I use to call the API:

```
    $key = 'mykey';
    $client = new BingClient($key,'json');
    $result = $client->get('Web',['Query' => $query]);
    return json_decode($result,true );
```

I am not rate limited. Maybe someone else has run into this problem before?

Edit: It's now returning results (I did not change code) but the only results are this stack overflow post. The first string is the query, the first object is it's result.

```
string(28) "Capital University%20twitter"
object(stdClass)#1008 (1) {
  ["d"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1013 (1) {
    ["results"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1014 (6) {
        ["__metadata"]=>
        object(stdClass)#1015 (2) {
          ["uri"]=>
          string(111)"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query='Capital University twitter'&$skip=0&$top=1"
          ["type"]=>
          string(9) "WebResult"
        }
        ["ID"]=>
        string(36) "4d5c4ee7-e5f8-44ac-90b3-a12c321e6033"
        ["Title"]=>
        string(59) "PHP Bing Search API returns an empty array - Stack Overflow"
        ["Description"]=>
        string(161) "Capital University%20twitter. And this is the code I use to call the API: $key = 'mykey'; $client = new BingClient($key,'json'); $result = $client->get ('Web ..."
        ["DisplayUrl"]=>
        string(67) "stackoverflow.com/questions/37556866/php-bing-search-api-returns..."
        ["Url"]=>
        string(86) "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556866/php-bing-search-api-returns-an-empty-array"
      }
    }
  }
}

string(29) "Capital University%20facebook"
object(stdClass)#1008 (1) {
  ["d"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1016 (1) {
    ["results"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you not need to regenerate the access API key every so often? Many API services like this, will only hold a valid key for a specific period of time (usually minutes).

Comment: Good thought - however my key hasn't changed.

Comment: Hi @Rob - nice name, by the way - please try to refrain from expletives in your posts on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was encoding the query incorrectly, which is why it linked to my stack post.

I was using `%20` or `+` as spaces. However, my client was handling that already. It's best to just use  for space.